# Removing Windows Phone System Tray Progress Indicator

Tags: windows-phone

I have searched for and found many posts that describe how to turn on the progress indicator. This is easy, 5 lines of code.

My problem is how do you then remove the indicator again after your async operation (usually on another thread somewhere) is finished? I am using an indeterminate indicator.

I have tried to call SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(page, null) to remove the indicator and set everything back again to how it looked before I created the indicator, but I am left with a black (or white if light theme) bar at the top of the screen (where my pivot control should be occupying with a nice background picture).

I don't want to make the system tray invisible, because it was not invisible to start with I assume.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using MVVM? If so, simply bind a variable in your View Model and change the value

```
<shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
    <shell:ProgressIndicator IsIndeterminate="true" IsVisible="{Binding IsDataDownload}"/>
</shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
```

Comment: Sorry for this late reply! Thanks for the answer, I will try this out in my current app - previously I ended up going with PerformanceProgressIndicator instead.